# Calling /../file.js function from inline declared html js gives - ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript

Im trying to call a function declared within my /js/file.js - from an inline js `<script>` tag'.

What happens is:

1. from /js/file.js I call a function `triggeredByJsFile()` declared in my inline `<script>` tag'
2. then from my inline `<script>` tag' I end up doing a callback to a function within the /js/file.js - `imagesLoaded()`

Im getting an error each time I try to callback to the /js/file.js function: "ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined"

My setup is as following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- JS file containing the function I want to call -->
  <script src="js/file.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">....</div>


    <script>
function triggeredByJsFile() {
  //does a lot of stuff and
  initiateSomething();
}

function initiateSomething() {
//Reference back to the js file
      imagesLoaded();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My /js/file.js**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

triggeredByJsFile();

    function imagesLoaded() {
        alert("IMAGES LOADED");
    }

});
```

**Error that firebug console shows me**

```
ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

imagesLoaded();
```

Figured I would be able to do this as long as I load my .js file before I do the actually reference / function call at the bottom?

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Are you sure the file path is correct? If so, please post the contents of that file as well.

Comment: ok sorry guys - guess a few perhaps important point missing. updated my description now

Comment: Could you show us where you call `triggeredByJsFile`? Is it called from the same file?

Comment: triggeredByJsFile is called from <script src="js/animation.js"></script> - all interction happens between the same js file and same html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imagesLoaded` is defined in the scope of the anonymous function you pass to `ready`.

It is not a global and cannot be called from other scripts.

Move it outside of the anonymous function to make it a global.

Comment: So I should basically move it outside of the $(document).ready function ?

Comment: Ok gotcha - correct answer to the issue in case. However with this new info in mind I cant access / initiate any other functions declared within my $(document).ready scope then - bum bum, so that brings a new issue to the table for me hehe. But thanks a lot